# cross-domain hosted Silverlight app not loading in a https webpage

Tags: silverlight, hosting, cross-domain

I want to provide silverlight app to my customer while hosting the app at my own site for streamlined maintenance.

- my Silverlight .xap  is hosted in, let say,  domain *me-supplier.com*
- i want to embed it in, let say, domain *my-customer.com*

It works perfectly for *http://my-customer.com*, not for ***https***://my-customer.com

- i have added the (*me-supplier.com* hosted) cross domain silverlight policy file to allow *my-customer.com*
- i have configured the mime types for .xap
- the silverlight app needs html dom access so the iframe approach is not viable i believe.

this works for javascript code, so why not for silverlight ? any idea, workaround ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the silverlight app also on https? If not, you might be hitting a security wall which does not allow to intermix http and https application domains

Comment: Yes! it works, thank you so much
so the SL2 RTW rule is: cross-domain is allowed but NOT (cross-domain+cross-scheme)

- to work on http://my-customer.com, my customer MUST use http://me-supplier.com/app.xap
- to work on https://my-customer.com, my customer MUST use https://me-supplier.com/app.xap

Answer (score 1):

I think the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73517/silverlight-cross-domain-policies) may explain it.

Generally HTTPS doesn't like you drawing data between domains within a page because the certificate is tied to the current domain.